# Face image quality assessment

Tags: computer-vision, image-processing, opencv, measurement

I'm trying to filter out bad face images (with artifacts) generated by [StyleGAN](https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan).
Is there a good image quality measurement mechanism in python for doing this?
I've tried using [BRISQUE](https://www.learnopencv.com/image-quality-assessment-brisque/?fbclid=IwAR2p95TZZTMgG0YrKplnpc6I5wJ8dxfwQbj6svH5bzPywujcK3G5Y2buYYk) but it is not showing good results (there are a lot of good quality images with higher scores then for bad quality images).

EDIT: These artifacts could be any kind of distortions, like eyes looking in a different directions, asymmetries (e.g. could be bad looking ear, assymetric eyes, ...), strange skin coloring, image messed up with the background like below image.[image: distoretd image]

More images could be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1myyRrdJVmm-3jMgBCXtnfNBpNsqIaxnh).

Comment: it would probably help if you could define these "artifacts" somehow.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I've edited my question with more details. But unfortunately I cannot define artifacts in a proper manner. I've tried also face landmarks detection, but still it succeeds on such distorted images.

Comment: Um, so your description is "something that seems perfectly plausible to a complex neural network trained on basically all statistics of an image class but isn't plausible to the human observer"? because bad news: you will have to write something that surpasses the GAN in being able to build images of faces...

Comment: (also, honestly, squinting a bit: that is the picture of a man with crossed eyes and a large scar on his left cheek in half-profile, not so "artifacty", to me)